# Pass the "at" command a string command instead of a path to a script whilst having it run immediately

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, at

Using the `at` command I can run a script once in the future:

```
at now + 1 minutes -f ~/script.sh
```

or run a string command ***now*** then return the result in the future:

```
echo "xyz" >> ~/testtest.txt | at now + 1 minute
```

How can I instead pass a string command (as per example 2) that runs in the future and not now (as per example 1)? E.g.

```
at now + 1 minutes -SOMEFLAG 'echo "xyz" >> ~/testtest.txt'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could single quote the command and pass it to `at` as is:

```bsh
echo 'echo "xyz" >> ~/testtest.txt' | at now + 1 minutes
```

Alternatively, if you're using bash or another script that supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), you can do:

```
at now + 1 minutes < <(echo 'echo "xyz" >> ~/testtest.txt')
```

This basically passes a filename to `at` just like passing it a file with commands.

However, using a heredoc as [suggested by Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582214/22222) should be more portable as it doesn't depend on your shell supporting process substitution.

Comment: @roaima it does, doesn't it? Wow. I have no clue why I jumped to process substitution instead of the obvious, simple approach. Answer updated, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use a here-document to pass the script to run later on the command line:

```
at now + 1 minute <<'END_AT'
echo 'xyz' >> ~/testtest.txt
END_AT
```

The here-document is quoted (by using `<<'END_AT'` rather than `<<END_AT`) to stop the current shell from expanding variables etc. in the script text.  The document will be passed to `at` on standard input.

Comment: This looks great, very useful for a myriad of situations, thanks!