# at & rm - command executed before pipe

Tags: rhel, rm, at

**System:** Redhat 7.8

**Goal:** I have a bash script which downloads a files to a folder named "logs" for viewing for a short time and **removes them at the end of the day.**

**What I've tried:**

```
rm -rfd logs | at 6pm
```

**What Doesn't Work:**

The above code is executing the `rm` command before it can be piped to the `at` command, and I never see the files I downloaded.

Comment: Related: [Pass the “at” command a string command instead of a path to a script whilst having it run immediately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582210/pass-the-at-command-a-string-command-instead-of-a-path-to-a-script-whilst-havi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
rm -rfd logs | at 6pm
```

executes `rm -rfd logs` **immediately**, and pipes its standard output (likely nothing) to `at 6pm`.

Instead, you need to output the string `rm -rfd logs` to standard output - any one of these ways should do:

1. type `at 6pm` then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then type `rm -rfd logs`, hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again, and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

   ```
    $ at 6pm
    warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
    at> rm -rfd logs
    at> <EOT>
    job 13 at Wed May 13 18:00:00 2020
   ```
2. similar to above, but using a *here document*

   ```
    at 6pm <<END_AT
    rm -rfd logs
    END_AT
   ```
3. a simple `echo` or `printf`

   ```
    printf -- 'rm -rfd logs' | at 6pm
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Needed `echo "rm -rfd logs" | at 6pm`

Source:
https://www.tecmint.com/linux-cron-alternative-at-command-to-schedule-tasks/